# "Unidentified function 'InStrRev' in expression" error in an Access query from C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

There is a function named "InStrRev" which is working fine in Access, but when I use that same function to get records in C# windows form then an error message pops up saying

> Unidentified function 'InStrRev' in expression.

Is there some way that I can use this function, or is there some other function I can use in my Access query that gets the last index of any character from a field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The older "Jet" driver for Access did not allow us to use VBA functions like `InStrRev()` in queries from external applications. Those functions would only be available to queries that were run from within Microsoft Access itself.

However, the OLEDB and ODBC drivers for the newer version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a "ACE") do allow external applications to make use of many of those built-in VBA functions. So, if your application uses

`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;` (OLEDB), or
`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};` (ODBC)

then the `InStrRev()` function will not work. However, if you use the newer "ACE" driver:

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;` (OLEDB), or
`Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};` (ODBC)

then those same `InStrRev()` queries will run without error.

The newer version of the Access Database Engine (and drivers) is available as a free download here:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent method in .Net is [String.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use it as follows:

```
var str = "foo bar foo";
var lastIndexOfFoo = str.LastIndexOf("foo");
```

Comment: no the data is coming from access and i want it there